# Memcached is installed on PHP 5.3.28 on MAMP 3.0.3, but not working

Tags: php, drupal, memcached, mamp, mamp-pro

I have a Drupal site running on fresh MAMP PRO 3.0.3 install with the PHP version 5.3.28 on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2.

I installed memcache with `pecl install memcache` and added the `extension=memcache.so` line in `php.ini`under the extensions section, but still Drupal shows multiple *You must enable the PECL memcached or memcache extension to use memcache.inc.* errors on top of the page.

phpinfo() on the Drupal root directory tells me that the configuration file loaded is at:

`/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php5.3.28.ini`

and the extension dir is:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`

> $ cat "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php5.3.28.ini" | grep memcache
>   extension=memcache.so
>
> $ ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ | grep memcache
>
> -rwxrwxr-x   1 user  admin    65K Mar 28 14:00 memcache.so*

What am I doing wrong or is this problem related to MAMP PRO 3? I've installed the memcached binaries with homebrew and the process is running.

I'm also using the *Individual PHP versions for every host* setting in MAMP.

When starting Apache, there is an error in the logs:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_new_interned_string
>     Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so in Unknown on line 0

What does this mean.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not get the memcache extension provided by pecl to work at all. I even installed PHP 5.3.14 but encountered the same problem. Then I cloned the [php-memcached-mamp](https://github.com/majksner/php-memcached-mamp) repository from github and used the memcached extension from there and it worked ok.

Comment: Same with MAMP 4.4 and PHP 5.6.32, the default memcached extension didn't work. The extension from the repository you've posted worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add [intl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) to your configuration.

Comment: PHP is already configured with *--enable-intl* and *--with-icu-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library* and *intl* section is listed on phpinfo() output.

Comment: @lollerskates666 - check [this thread](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/38) out, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this problem and another post that helped me fix it.  macports installed php-config53 (not php-config) and I had a vagrant php-config from an old php 5.4 install.  Removed /usr/bin/php-config and symlinked php=config53 -> php-config, re-rean pecl install memcache-beta and it worked.